# Statistics random variable change

Tags: statistics

I have a question about my statistic homework. We have to generate n=100,500,1000 random numbers uniformly distributed on the (0,1) interval with rand() function . And i have to generate n values of the random variable X with the distribution function F given  :

$
F(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 , x\leq 0
\\ 
1-e^{-x}, x>0
\end{matrix}\right.
$


How can i do this in excel ? I tried to implement the function in excel after i generate the numbers with rand() but i don't know how exactly i can do this.Or how can i transform from distribution function to random variable X ?

Comment: How would you do it in principle? Also have a look at the inverse method.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $U\sim\operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$ be a standard uniform random variable and $X\sim F$. Then, $X\sim F^{-1}(U)$.

Solve $u=1-e^{-x}$ for $x$ to get $F^{-1}(u)$.  Then use `rand()` to generate a bunch of $U$'s and substitute these pseudo-random numbers into the function $F^{-1}(u)$.